# jquery scrollleft doesn't work on Chrome (webkit broswer)?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollto, jquery-1.9

I have read many threads online about $.scrolleft does not work on chrome or a webkit browser. The solutions/ answers I have read still cannot solve my problem. Here are the code,

html,

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="background"><img src="styles/images/mountain.png" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

jquery,

```
$(document.body).scrollLeft(($(document).width() - $('body').width() )/2);
```

the rest of codes (css) are in [jsfiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/hDdKh/)

I have also upload the files into my [website](http://lauthiamkok.net/bin/scrollto/scrollto.php).

It works on firefox, opera, and IE9, but **not** on chrome and safari.

If I used [scrollto](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin, none of the browser is working!

Any idea what I have done wrong??

Comment: looks like `overflow-y:hidden` on the body cause the issue

Comment: yes you are right. so what should i do if i don't want the scrollbar appear on the right side? I just need the scrollbar at the bottom horizontally. thanks.

Comment: oh, if i take `overflow-y:hidden;` off, it now won't work on firefox! :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#el").animate({ scrollLeft:110 }, "fast");
```

fast - 0 mb